# MessageFormat vs StringBuffer

Tags: java, string

I see, that in Java you can build strings with

- `MessageFormat` and a string like `"You said {0} just now"`
- `StringBuffer` and a construct like

  ```
  StringBuffer mail = new StringBuffer("Dear ");
  mail.append(user.name);
  mail.append(",\nCongratulations!");
  ....
  ```
- there may be other good options, string concatenation is not one of them

So, which method should I use? My thoughts are: I have 5-6 standard texts where I have to replace some of the contents dynamically. I think it will be better to have the texts as constants somewhere (class with constants or properties file) and just make the quick replacement when I need it. Otherwise I will have strings in the middle of my source code that may be changed one day, like `StringBuffer("Dear ")`.

Do I have an even better option?

Comment: There is also StringBuilder which is another alternative to consider.

Comment: MessageFormat [appears to use StringBuffer internally](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.Object[],%20java.lang.StringBuffer,%20java.text.FieldPosition%29).

Comment: In its current form, this question is too subjective.

Comment: StringBuilder is not much of an improvement on either StringBuffer or MessageFormat.

Comment: StringBuilder has been the suggested drop in replacement for StringBuffer for over 8 years. It's not much of an improvement but IMHO you shouldn't use StringBuffer if you can avoid it.

Comment: could you please give a reference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String str = new StringBuffer().append("Hello").append("World").toString();
    System.out.println(str);

            //print Hello World 

             it contain into package import java.text.MessageFormat;
             "When you using Message format"
              Object[] values = { "123456", "asdfjk" };

    String output = MessageFormat.format("Value 1 equals: {0} and Value 2 equals{1}", values);
    System.out.println(output);
    // prints:
    // The value of value 1 is: 123456 The value of value 2 is: asdfjk
```

Answer (score 1):

If it's emails you'd like to generate, I'd recommend neither approach.  I'd rather see a Velocity template for the lettter or email body that mapped values from Java objects in its context.  That would be much easier to understand and maintain.  The templates can be externalized from your code, so changes are easier.

Comment: That doesn't answer the OPs question, which was about the pros and cons of MessageFormat and StringBuffer.

Comment: thanks for the hint, maybe it will be useful for someone else, but my question is really about the pros and cons of MessageFormat and StringBuffer

Comment: That's right, Philipp, but it does answer this: "Do I have an even better option?"  I think that MessageFormat and StringBuffer are both equally wrongheaded and should not be considered for the implied use case.

Comment: @duffymo what do you use then if none of these two?

Comment: If you read my response you'll know - Velocity is my choice.  Your way means embedding everything in code.  That's not a good idea, in my opinion.  http://velocity.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

You should what you believe is the simplest and clearest.  Personally I would use

```
String mail = "Dear " + user.name + ",\nCongratulations!";
```

It's shorter and more efficient than using StringBuffer or MessageFormat.

Comment: Note that what peter said is quite accurate, even if you don't want to believe it.  String concatenation through "+" is usually as efficient as any StringBuffer solution, and since the compiler knows about String and "+" it could do further optimizations that it might find more difficult if StringBuffer calls were used directly.  Don't go with your intuition and assume + is going to be slow.

Comment: In Java 5.0 and later, the `+` uses `StringBuilder` which is slightly faster than `StringBuffer`

Comment: @user1414745 can you clarify what you mean?

Answer (score 1):

As suggested in various comment `StringBuilder` is fastest implementation for string concatenation. `MessageFormat` internally uses `StringBuilder` with regex overheads.